# How to prevent Firefox from clearing my remembered passwords

Tags: firefox, passwords

Whenever Firefox updates itself it clears all my remembered passwords, so I'm forced to log in to those sites manually again.

Is there a way to prevent this? It's really annoying.

Comment: This isn't normal behavior for Firefox. Can you list all the addons you currently use? One of them might be the culprit.

Comment: Adblock, fiddlerhook, firebug, and modify headers.  I'll try leaving them disabled and see if this solves it next time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to file > options > privacy > Firefox will:

Make sure the drop down menu says Remember History.

If this is only happening with some sites, the cause may be this http://www.dailygyan.com/2008/08/force-firefox-to-remember-password-of.html

That website will show you how to disable Firefox respecting the "autocomplete=off" flag that some websites send. They respect it by default for security reasons.

Also, double check to make sure that "Remember Passwords" in the security menu is enabled (and doubly so when it comes time to upgrade your install).

If none of these work for you, you may want to uninstall Firefox, run CCleaner and select registry to clean your registry, then reinstall the latest version of Firefox from their website. Once you've done all that, make sure all the options are set to what you believe they should be and test it for functionality.

Comment: The logic with my response was that either the OP may accidentally be switching one of these before/after the update or the update may be messing with one of these settings. By knowing what settings to look for it may be of some help to him.